# Database return me last id

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, tcpdf

I want to display all data from a table in tcpdf but this code returns me the last id.

```
$students = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array(
    'class_id' => $class_id , 
    'year' => $running_year
))->result_array();

foreach($students as $row):

    $id = $this->db->get_where('student', array(
        'student_id' => $row['student_id']
    ))->row()->student_id;

    $nume = $this->db->get_where('student', array(
        'student_id' => $row['student_id']
    ))->row()->name;

endforeach; 

$html =<<<EOD
$id <br/>
$nume
<br/>
```

I expect to view

```
id1
name1
id2
name2
```

...
Display the last id but from the first to the penultimate is not displayed.
In PHP work very well the code that I provided below.

```
<?php                  
$students = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array(
    'class_id' => $class_id , 
    'year' => $running_year
))->result_array();

foreach($students as $row):
?>

<tr>
<th class="stil">
<?php echo $count++;?></th>
<td class="stil"><?php 
echo $this->db->get_where('student' , array(
    'student_id' => $row['student_id']
))->row()->student_id;
?></td>
```

The PHP generates a page with some results.

[image: The PHP generates a page with some results.]

Comment: You're currently replacing/overwriting the values of the variables `$id` and `$nume` on each iteration of your loop. So in the end, it will only contain the values from the last iteration. If you want to output all of the rows, then you should either have you output inside the `foreach`-loop or append current row data to the `$html`-variable.

Comment: You should also not make more queries than you need to make. You should make one single query with a join between the `enroll` and `student`-table, fetching all the data you need in one go instead of making queries inside `foreach`-loop. Also, in the `foreach`-loop, you're making the exact same query for each property you need. That makes no sense. If you want multiple columns from the same row, make _one_ query and then use the same result to get the different columns.

Comment: The reason the added HTML code works is because you're outputting the data _inside_ the loop, not after, like in your first example.